# Missing panel/tab

Tags: panel

The panel on the right with wrench and the modifier and stuff has suddenly gone missing and there's no way i can retrieve it. But when I go to "new" its there, but not on the project i'm working on. Please help, because I can't restart the project.[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the .blend file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and send the link to be able to have a look and help you?

Answer (score 1):

You have switched the  3D Edit window to full screen mode :)

To Toggle back: hover your mouse over the 3D viewport and use the shortcut keys **Shift** + **Spacebar**